# Select multiple fields / Bind Subset of object to model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-options

Assuming we have the following object structure: { id: 1, name: 'name', description: 'test' }

We can select an object from a drop down using the following code:

```
ng-options="item as item.name for item in items"
```

and select an individual ID with:

```
ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items"
```

Instead of selecting the whole object or just one individual field, is there a way to select multiple fields? e.g.

```
ng-options="(item.id, item.description) as item.name for item in items"
```

Essentially I would like to return a subset of an object and not the whole object itself. The whole object in my case contains too many fields.

Comment: You could just use id and when you send it to elsewhere just map the original object to provide required fields. Or just have the `items` itself hold only least minimal fields. There is no point in doing it in the ng-options. You should not use ng-options syntax (even if possible) for a mapper.

Comment: In short, no there is not a way to map it to specific fields.

Comment: @PSL - I modified the items to hold the least minimal fields. Worked great, thanks!